# What exactly was Tatsuya afraid that Mizuki could discover with her sensitive eyes?

Tags: the-irregular-at-magic-high-school

When Tatsuya learns of Mizuki's sensitive eyes, he thinks to himself that he has to take care not to let her discover something about him.

**Unmarked spoilers below.**

What was it that she could discover with her ability?

Possible things:

- The seal Miyuki placed on his abilities (since mantaining the seal uses up her magic processor, it is a kind of ongoing effect).
- His special abilities. Like she could sense his use of elemental sight.
- The fact he was not a born magician (his mother used a magic surgery to implant a processor in his brain).
- That she could catch him using flash casting
- Something else?

Also, if the source material can be referenced (like the novels or something), all the better.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding was correct, he was afraid that she would discover his unique constitution (the extremely high psion count he had) which allowed him to use some of his really overpowered and rarely seen spells such as Gram Demolition. Knowing that he has this specific constitution would make him a suspect when spells that require this constitution are cast.

Tatsuya tried (and failed miserably) to keep a low profile and avoid divulging any information about his powers, as some of these were national secrets (due to him being a special member of the JSDF 101 Independent Magic-Equipped Battalion) and the Yotsuba wanted his and Miyuki's identity as members of the family to remain secret.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

first - high psion count

second - use of "Pledge" to limit his powers (including psion count)

**Mental Interference Magic - "Pledge"** is an Outer Systematic Magic. Outer Systematic Magic does not deal with physical objects but spirits or to be more precise pushions.

Mental Interference Magic though not directly deals with spirits (information bodies with pushion core) but there is a high chance that it involves dealing with pushions (*In Visitors' Arc - it was Miyuki's magic - Cocytus - which could destroy the parasites. Tatsuya's "Far Strike" could only strip the parasite's outer psion body and force them to enter hibernation.*)

**P.S. - Cocytus is a form of Mental Interference Magic.**

Mizuki has a special pair of eyes which can see pushions. This made Tatsuya afraid of Mizuki. Even among magicians who are sensitive to pushions, Mizuki is a special case. Her eye is known as **"Crystal Eyes"** (Eyes that can see God). This allows her to see even different shades in spirit's colors.

Comment: What is pledge? Sorry, i've seen only the anime. Welcome to Anime.SE nice answer.